# Integer number too large

Tags: java

Hi I'm having trouble understanding why this isn't working

```
if(Long.parseLong(morse) == 4545454545){
     System.out.println("2");
}
```

Where morse is just a String of numbers. The problem is it says Integer number too large: 4545454545, but I'm sure a Long can be much longer than that.

Comment: I am sure you must have realized the mistake till now.. You are comparing an integer and a Long. 

The max value of Integer is 2147483647, which is approximately half of what you have typed there.

Comment: yup never knew about the L in the end to qualify as Long thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use `4545454545l` or `4545454545L` to qualify it as `long`. Be default , `4545454545` is an `int` literal and `4545454545` is out of range of `int`.

*It is recommended to use uppercase alphabet `L` to avoid confusion , as `l` and `1` looks pretty similar*

You can do :

```
if(Long.valueOf(4545454545l).equals(Long.parseLong(morse)) ){
     System.out.println("2");
}
```

OR

```
if(Long.parseLong(morse) == 4545454545l){
   System.out.println("2");
}
```

As per [JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with **an ASCII letter L or l (ell)**; otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Comment: Since `parseLong()` returns a primitive long, there's no need to use `.equals()` - `==` will work just fine.

Comment: *Don't* use `l`, use `L`. Both mean the same thing but the former can cause confusion as it can look like a `1`.

Answer (score 4):

If your integer value is larger than `2147483647`, as your literal is then you need to use a long literal:

`4545454545L`

...note the `L` at the end, which is the difference between a long and an int literal. A lower case `l` works too, but is less readable as it's easily confused with a 1 (not a great thing when you're dealing with a number!)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `4545454545L` or  `4545454545l` to qualify it as long.

Comment: Long.parseLong() returns a long (primitive type). Using == is fine.